# Don't escape specific variable in ErlyDTL

Tags: erlang, erlydtl

ErlyDTL has an option `auto_escape` (which is set to `true` by default), which makes sure that all variables are escaped during rendering of the template.
Is there a way not to escape a specific variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out this can be done with a `safe` filter. Like this:
`{{var|safe}}`
More information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#safe